# WPF C#: How to get ID from a selected row in ListView to open a unique window through event handler?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, listview, eventhandler

I created an mysql database with a table "activemeassurements". I run a query in `BatchesVm.cs` that outputs rows that have the latest date and have a unique batch id to a `<ListView>` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. I want to be able to show the selected item in a more detailed manner in another window whenever I doubleclick on it. The binding works fine, and it is connected to the correct database. However, I have struggled to find a way to retrieve the ID of the selected row in <`ListView>` to use in the next Window. This is my first time working with wpf.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="P5_WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:P5_WPF" xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:P5_WPF.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding allBatches}" x:Name="batcheslist"  Margin="72,100,59,63" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=BatchID}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=batchid" Header="batch ID" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Temp}" Header="Latest temp meassurements"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Humidity}" Header="Latest humidity meassurements" />
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=date}" Header="Date" Width="150"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
    </Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new BatchesVm();
        }
        private void batchesList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //I want to open single batch window with the id from the selected item.

            SingleBatch_Window single = new SingleBatch_Window();
            single.Show();
        }
    }
```

My `BatchesVm.cs` C# file that contains the ItemsSource for the ListView:

```
public class BatchesVm
    {
        public DataView allBatches { get; private set; }
        public BatchesVm()
        {
            var CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CS))
                {
                    string CmdString = "select batchid,Temp,Humidity,date from (select batchid,Temp,Humidity,date,row_number() over(partition by batchid order by date desc) as rn from aktivemeassurements) t where t.rn = 1;";
                    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, connection);
                    adapter.Fill(dt);
                }
                allBatches = dt.DefaultView;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cannot establish connection");
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**- How do I:**

- use the event handler `batchesList_MouseDoubleClick,` and get the
  batchid of the selected row and use it to open a unique window?

========================================================================

Comment: The click event "sender" will give the cell where the click occurred.

Comment: thank you. Sender has this value: {System.Windows.Controls.ListView Items.Count:1}, where count defines which cell was clicked. How do I retrieve this "Count" value? @jdweng

Comment: Sender.Items[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering the same heres the solution: Through `@Jdweng`'s help I figured out how to retrieve ID from the DataView `allBatches`.

From `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
private void batchesList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //get index of the selected row.
                int itemindex = batcheslist.Items.IndexOf(batcheslist.SelectedItems[0]);
                BatchesVm a = new BatchesVm();
                //get id of selected row.
                int batchId = a.allBatchIds[itemindex];

                SingleBatch_Window single = new SingleBatch_Window(batchId);
                single.Show();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please choose a Batch.");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }  
        }
```

ViewModel:

```
//Dataview of the selected sql table from query
            allBatches = dt.DefaultView;

            //converting DataView allBatches to a generic list.
            allBatchIds = allBatches.ToTable().Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                .Select(dr => dr.Field<int>("BatchID")).ToList();
```